# Extracting archive by piping contents of archive into the tar command

Tags: pipe, tar

I am creating a self-extracting archive and I have got the basic thing going.

However I want to set the command that extracts the archive contents
 `tail -n+$ARCHIVE_START_LINE $0` into a variable. I can't get this part to work

I have tried many things here - one is shown below for explanation. (Note this is a simplified example and the question is as much about understanding pipes etc as solving the problem.)

```
#!/bin/bash
export TMPDIR=`mktemp -d /tmp/selfextract.XXXXXX`
ARCHIVE_START_LINE=`awk '/^__ARCHIVE_BELOW__/ {print NR + 1; exit 0; }' $0`

# This works...
tail -n+$ARCHIVE_START_LINE $0 | tar xzv -C $TMPDIR

# .. but this is the kind of thing I want. But it doesn't work...
ARCHIVE_CONTENTS=`tail -n+$ARCHIVE_START_LINE $0`
echo $ARCHIVE_CONTENTS | tar xzv -C $TMPDIR
# I get: gzip: stdin is a multi-part gzip file -- not supported
```

I am on Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 2):

All of your problems are explained in [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters), but I'll repeat the relevant parts here.

First, `$var` in a shell script does not mean “the value of the variable `var`”, it means “take the value of the variable `var`, split it into words and interpret each word as a wildcard pattern”. To avoid these extra steps, put double quotes around variable substitutions: `"$var"` means “the value of the variable `var`”. **Always put double quotes around variable substitutions and command substitutions** unless you know and understand why need to leave them out.

Second, `echo` doesn't exactly print its argument: it interprets some options, and in some shells, it interprets backslash escape sequences. Furthermore `echo` prints a trailing newline, which you could remove with the `-n` option. Gzipped data never looks like an option and bash's `echo` treats backslashes literally by default, but in general, don't use `echo` on unknown data, use `printf %s` instead.

```
printf %s "$ARCHIVE_CONTENTS" | tar xzv -C "$TMPDIR"
```

This is guaranteed to feed the value of the variable `ARCHIVE_CONTENTS` to `tar` exactly.

The remaining problem, and one you can't solve without using a fundamentally different approach, is that most shells (all the shells I've seen apart from zsh) truncate the value of variables at the first null byte (this is because they use C null-terminated strings under the hood). So the variable `ARCHIVE_CONTENTS` in fact contains only the beginning of the archive file, up to the first null byte. **You can't use a shell to manipulate binary data.**

Answer (score 1):

why not use a here document like in the old days ?

```
 #!/bin/bash
 export TMPDIR=`mktemp -d /tmp/selfextract.XXXXXX`

 ## other stuff

 base64 -d <<EOF | tar xvf -C $TMPDIR
 ## base64 encoded
 EOF
```

you produce base64 encoded this way

```
 tar cf - my_dir | base64 > /some/place
```

(including it int self extract archive is left to the reader)

Answer (score 0):

You may be inadvertently shell-expanding the contents of your archive. Try quoting your variable.

Replace

```
echo $ARCHIVE_CONTENTS | tar xzv -C $TMPDIR
```

with

```
echo "$ARCHIVE_CONTENTS" | tar xzv -C $TMPDIR
```

You also may need to avoid appending a newline with `echo -n`

Comment: thanks. I tried both these but I still get the error `gzip: stdin is a multi-part gzip file -- not supported
`